# Converting XML data to JSON on ReactJs

Tags: javascript, json, xml, reactjs

i am working on healthcare project and i have to import some medicen data from another server . the other server data is type xml , and i want to convert it to json to be on my API .

```
fetch ("http://api.com/rest/api/something&q=")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then((response) => {
                parseString(responseText, function (err, result) {
                    console.log(response)
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('fetch', err)
            })
},
```

i get this erorr :

> fetch ReferenceError: parseString is not defined

i am using ReactJs so please can someone help me to get the correct way to convert XML to JSON ?

Comment: This might help https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

Comment: This is another way to do it https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js

Comment: thank you , i will check it out right now

Answer (score 1):

install these two npm Lib

1.npm install react-native-xml2js

2.npm install --save xml-js

```
step-1-----
    import axios from "axios";
    const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;  //step-1 here


 axios.get(your api url here,
        {
          headers:{Authorization:this.state.token}
      }).then(response => {
            parseString(response, function (err, result) {
console.log("response----"+response.data)

//step--2 here
var convert = require('xml-js');
var xml = response.data
var result1 = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: true, spaces: 4});
var result2 = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: false, spaces: 4});
console.log("result1----"+result1);
console.log("result2----"+result2);
//step--2 end here

            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('fetch', err)
        })
```

use which result suitable for you...
It's worked for me in my React-native project